# How to pass data that is non JSON serializable from flask to javascript file?

Tags: python, json, flask

In my server.py, I have a list that keeps track of names:

```
data = [
"Jim",
"Stanley",
"Michael",
"Kevin",
"Kelly"
]
```

doing {{data|tojson}} doesn't work for me because data in this format is not serializable. Doing `return render_template('ppc.html', data=data)`also doesn't seem to let the js file access data in server.py. I also tried `'{{data}}'`this format sugested in some posts but none of those seem to work. Does anyone have any other way?

Comment: What do you mean by "non-serializable", exactly? And why would a simple list of strings not be that?

Comment: it is a type error give by python. JSON serializable data is like {"name": name}

Comment: Present your [MCVE], **clearly** describing your goal, your attempt, your expectation, the instead result, and any pertinent details.

Answer (score 0):

Use `jsonify` method. It will enable returning `list` from `view`. Documentation for [jsonify](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/api/?highlight=jsonify#flask.json.jsonify).

Here is an example of how to load data in template using Javascript.

Folder structure:

```
├── app.py
├── static
│   └── demo.js
└── templates
    └── simple.html
```

`app.py`:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, jsonify

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/get_data", methods=['GET'])
def get_data():
    data = ["Captain America", "Hulk", "Thor", "Wolverine"]
    return jsonify(data)

@app.route("/")
def index():
    return render_template("simple.html")

app.run(debug=True)
```

`simple.html`:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Marvel Characters</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h3>List of Marvel Characters loaded from JS</h3>
        <div id="result"></div>
        <script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='demo.js') }}"></script>    
    </body>
</html>
```

`demo.js`:

```
window.addEventListener("load", function(){
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            var data = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
            var result = document.getElementById("result");
            for(var i=0;i<data.length; i++){
                result.innerHTML += data[i]+"<br>";
            }           
        }
    };
    xhttp.open("GET", "/get_data", true);
    xhttp.send();
});
```

Output:

[image: output of data loading from JS]